# Swift iOS apply CIPhotoEffectNoir to video in playback, when button is tapped slash is through play button

Tags: ios, swift2, avfoundation, core-image

I have an app that allows users to record 8 second videos then preview them on a different view controller. The URL for the video is sent like so

```
            let url = outputFilePath
            let previewController = PreviewViewController(nibName: "PreviewViewController", bundle: nil)
            previewController.media = Media.Video(url: url!)

            self.presentViewController(previewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Then an enum is used to differentiate between incoming data and set up the AVPlayerController to play the video

```
 override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    customView.frame = self.view.bounds
    playerViewController.view.frame = self.view.bounds
    playerViewController.showsPlaybackControls = false
    switch self.media! {
    case .Photo(let image): self.imageView.image = image


    case .Video(let url): self.playVideo(url)

    }



}
```

Here is the code for playVideo:

```
func playVideo(url: NSURL) {


    print("display video for url : \(url.absoluteString)")


     player = AVPlayer(URL: url)


       self.customView.addSubview(playerViewController.view)


    playerViewController.player = player

    self.player.play()





 player.actionAtItemEnd = .None

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self,
    selector: "playerItemDidReachEnd:",
     name: AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification,
     object: player.currentItem)


        }
```

Finally I am trying to filter the video to black and white but I get a line through the play button symbol and I am not sure why, here is the code:

```
    @IBAction func filterTapped(sender: UIButton) {

    player.pause()
    //terminate player and introduce new player
    switch self.media! {
    case .Photo(let image): self.imageView.image = image


    case .Video(let url): self.createBlackAndWhiteFilterForVideo(url)

    }



}




  func createBlackAndWhiteFilterForVideo(url: NSURL){

        //B&W Filter for Video



    asset = AVAsset(URL: url)



    let composition = AVVideoComposition(asset: asset, applyingCIFiltersWithHandler: { request in

        let seconds = CMTimeGetSeconds(request.compositionTime)
        let filtered = request.sourceImage.imageByApplyingFilter("CIPhotoEffectNoir", withInputParameters: [kCIInputTimeKey: seconds])
        request.finishWithImage(filtered, context: nil)
    })





        let plyItem = AVPlayerItem(asset: asset)


        plyItem.videoComposition = composition

        player = AVPlayer(playerItem: plyItem)
        player.replaceCurrentItemWithPlayerItem(plyItem)

        playerViewController.player = self.player
        player.play()
          print("player was tapped")









}
```

If any one could supply some help i'd really appreciate it as I'm very stuck